# Remove leaflet zoom control outline(?)

Tags: css, leaflet, mobile-devices

In every browser on every mobile device I've tried, my zoom control buttons have a light grey outline that doesn't show up on desktop browsers. I have tried a lot of css to get rid of it but nothing works. Does anyone know how to remove it?

[image]

This is my CSS for the controls, which does everything I need on desktop browsers but doesn't remove this outline sort of thing on mobile devices:

```
.leaflet-control-container {
    box-shadow: none !important;
    outline: 0 !important;
}

.leaflet-bar {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.leaflet-bar a, .leaflet-bar a:hover {
    background-color: #f0b034;
    border: 1px solid #065428;
}

.leaflet-bar a:first-child, .leaflet-bar a:last-child {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #065428;
}
```

This is the live page I currently use for testing: [click](http://zoiglapp.bplaced.net/#/map/12.5655/-12.5635)

Comment: Only if you can post the code that you are using, people here can improvise and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In desktop browser, there **is** a shadow around the Zoom Control. It is defined by `.leaflet-bar` class (see [Leaflet CSS line 209](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/stable/dist/leaflet.css#L209)).

```css
.leaflet-bar {
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
}
```

For touch (mobile) devices, this definition is overriden by `.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar` class (see [line 380](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/stable/dist/leaflet.css#L380)).

```css
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
    border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
```

You should be able to remove it by overriding this `border` property in your CSS.

```css
.leaflet-touch .leaflet-bar {
    border: none;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/37/